# Azure Offline Sync - How to use "Contains"

Tags: c#, azure-mobile-services

I have an Azure Table and I want to sync it offline on my mobile device, Everything works fine if I pass single `where` clause such as following

```
var query = todoTable.CreateQuery().Where(c => c.Id == "some id here");
await todoTable.PullAsync(null, query);
```

But I have a `List` which contains multiple IDs such as

```
List<string> IDS = new List<string>();
IDS.Add("Some ID 1");
IDS.Add("Some ID 2");
```

and I am trying to pass that in my query as following to only get items with specific Ids

```
var query = todoTable.CreateQuery().Where(c => IDS.Contains(c.Id));
await todoTable.PullAsync(null, query);
```

But this seems not to be working,

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> var query = todoTable.CreateQuery().Where(c => IDS.Contains(c.Id));
>
> await todoTable.PullAsync(null, query);

Per my understanding, your pull operation would execute the following request against your mobile backend:

```
GET https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/tables/{your-table-name}?$filter=((id eq 'Some ID 1') or (id eq 'Some ID 2'))
```

**TEST:**

[image]

Based on my testing, the above pull operation could work as expected on my side. I recommend you use [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture the network trace when invoking the pull operation to make sure that you could retrieve the records as expected. Moreover, you could follow [Debugging the Offline Cache](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/client/#debugging-the-offline-cache).

**UPDATE:**

I checked this issue on my C# mobile app backend to narrow down this issue. I set `config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy` to `IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always` under `Startup.MobileApp.cs` for retrieving detailed error messages. And I found that I could encounter the following error:

[image]

I assumed that we may hit the [ODataValidationSettings.MaxNodeCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.odata.query.odatavalidationsettings.maxnodecount(v=vs.118).aspx) which is used to determine the maximum of the nodes inside the $filter syntax tree. Then, I decorated my action as follows to increase the MaxNodeCount limitation, and found that the query could work as expected.

```
[EnableQuery(MaxNodeCount =1000)]
public IQueryable<ToDoItem> GetAllTodoItems()
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply, I get the following error `The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable ` which I don't under what is causing it so I made a terrible assumption that it was the `contains` part causing the issue. I am trying to use the fiddler (first time using fiddler so still trying to understand how to capture traffic getting out of android emulator.

Comment: Have you configured [App Service Authentication / Authorization](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-auth) for your mobile back-end? I assumed that your table name may be incorrect. You could just access your table endpoint via the browser to narrow down this issue. If you have enabled authentication, you could visit `https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/{provider-name}` for logging, then access `https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/tables/{your-table-name}?X-ZUMO-VERSION=2.0.0` to make sure you could retrieve the table records.

Comment: In order to configure fiddler for Android Emulators, you could follow https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2013/04/03/configuring-fiddler-to-be-a-proxy-for-android-emulators-in-eclipse/

Comment: Hi Bruce, Yes I can connect to the table using POSTMAN directly and get the data `https://{myapp}.azurewebsites.net/tables/todoitem` also the following works `var query = todoTable.CreateQuery().Where(c => c.Id == "some id here");` for single item which means table name is correct otherwise it will show me the error on single item also, the error happens only happens when i try to use `Contains`

Comment: I just used [Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client 3.1.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client/3.1.0), what's the version of your Mobile App client SDK?

Comment: I am using 4.0.2

Comment: Noticed something - I can use `CONTAINS` for the list of 20 IDs but if I add one more ID to the list and make it 21 and use it in `Contains`, I get the error - Is this the limitation?

Comment: Why is this happening I am unsure, it could be the length of filters but I am unable to find any reference to it so I ended up dividing IDs to bunch of 15s something like `for (int i = 0; i < IDs.Count; i = i + 15)
                    {
                        var items = IDs.Skip(i).Take(15);
                        var query = todoTable.CreateQuery().Where(c => items.Contains(c.Id);
                        await todoTable.PullAsync(null, query);
                    }`

Comment: I updated my answer with some investigations, you could refer to it.

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed reply, I had no idea about this, I set the MaxNodeCount = 1000 in C# backend (so if default 100 can take 20 IDs, 1000 should take 200 IDs) although it fails again :) Do i need to change anything in config - In any case I think this gives me enough direction to move forward, I highly appreciate your help :)