# Sync specific data from Azure to Xamarin (Offline sync)

Tags: azure, xamarin, synchronization, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to "filter" which data I want to sync from Azure. However I cannot seem to get "Where" to work. Any ideas?

```cs
var allItems = await GetMyListItems();
var myIdsInList = allEdrops.Select(c => c.Id.ToLower()).ToList();
```

This one doesn't work:

```cs
var query = this.myTable.CreateQuery().Where(c => myIdsInList.Contains(c.Id.ToLower())); //DONT WORK
```

This one Works (But get ALL values, which I don't want)

```cs
var query = this.myTable.CreateQuery();  //WORKS

await this.myTable.PullAsync("allmyTableItems", query);
```

Comment: does it work if you take out the toLower() iirc something is telling me that would cause issues

Comment: No. Put it there since I thought I would get any result if the caption was differenting.

Comment: Are you talking about `await this.myTable.PullAsync("allmyTableItems", this.myTable.CreateQuery().Where(c => myIdsInList.Contains(c.Id.ToLower())));` does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `SyncTable` in the `MobileServiceClient` and append any LINQ queries.

```cs
readonly MobileServiceClient _mobileServiceClient = new MobileServiceClient("Azure Mobile App URL");

async Task<List<MyModel>> GetItems()
{
    return await _mobileServiceClient.GetSyncTable<MyModel>().Where(c => myIdsInList.Contains(c.Id.ToLower())).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Here is a generic class that I use to interact with Azure Mobile Apps using the Client SDK: https://github.com/brminnick/UITestSampleApp/blob/master/Src/UITestSampleApp/Services/AzureService.cs

Comment: The `GetItems` method would just filter data against the local SQLite data store. Per my understanding, op wants to sync specific data from Azure side to local SQLite db, so I think the problem would be focused on the `PullAsync` operation, and the query  `await this.myTable.PullAsync("allmyTableItems", this.myTable.CreateQuery().Where(c => myIdsInList.Contains(c.Id.ToLower())));`.

Answer (score 0):

Using fiddler to capture the network traces, you could find that your filter query would look like this:

```
GET https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/tables/{table-name}?$filter=((((((((((id eq '1') or (id eq '2')) or (id eq '3')) or (id eq '4')) or (id eq '5')) or (id eq '6')) or (id eq '7')) or (id eq '8')) or (id eq '9')) or (id eq '10'))
```

For a small number of Ids, I could retrieve the records as expected. For your scenario, you may touch `maxQueryString` under [requestLimits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits/) from the Web server (IIS). For C# backend, you may also need to improve the `maxQueryStringLength` under [httpRuntime Element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.100).aspx) for ASP.NET run-time.

Moreover, you may hit the [ODataValidationSettings.MaxNodeCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.odata.query.odatavalidationsettings.maxnodecount(v=vs.118).aspx) which is used to determine the maximum of the nodes inside the `$filter` syntax tree.

For troubleshooting this issue, you could [Enable diagnostics logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log) for your mobile app, then you could log into KUDU to view the log files or just log into Azure Portal to check the stream logging under "MONITORING > Log stream" blade of your mobile app. Additionally, for C# backend, you could follow this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48972334/azure-offline-sync-how-to-use-contains/48981956#48981956) to set `MaxNodeCount`. For Node.js backend, I did not find any tutorials, you could follow [30 DAYS OF AZURE MOBILE APPS](https://shellmonger.com/30-days-of-azure-mobile-apps-the-table-of-contents/) for investigating, or maybe you need to iterate the `Ids` and send multiple requests for syncing your data.